# Android How to clear stack of an application if its open before launching by another appliction?

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-stack

i am launching another application through my application,so i want to check is any instance of that application is already in stack or not? if exist then clear all instance before launch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you be looking for the following flags to add to the Intent you start the other application with:

[FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)

Comment: is it possible to clear another application stack through FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK from other appliction?

Comment: Well that is exactly what the documentation states. In fact it can _only_ be used to clear the stack of another application, because as the documentation also states the flag _must_ be used in conjunction with FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK (by the way, in Android context you usually refer to "tasks" rather than "applications")

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this flags to your intent

```
Intent intent= getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.address");

intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```